# How to filter an array properly JS/TS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte

In my svelte component I have an input box with a datalist (I refuse to use any other select structure as I cant get the arrow keys to work upon select). I have a list of times by the function timesArray() such as "13:00". When the user inputs 13, it should show "12:00", "13:00" and "14:00". I have attached my code below of what I've tried but no luck.

If you aren't familiar with svelte it's basically js/ts code within a component using {}.What is wrong with my filter function below? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    <script>
    function timesArray(): string[] {
     let times: string[] = [];
    
     for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
     if (i >= 10) {
     times.push(i.toString() + ":00");
          } else {
     times.push("0" + i.toString() + ":00");
          }
        }
    
     return times;
      }
    </script>
    <input id="datahere"
    bind:value={internalTimeRange.End}
    on:blur={valueChanged}
    bind:this={endInput}
    list={timesArray()}
    /> <datalist id={timesArray()}>
        {#each timesArray().filter((value, index, arr)=>{
               let no =+internalTimeRange.End.slice(0,2)
               let val =+value.slice(0,2)
              console.log("no", no, "val",val)
              console.log("index",timesArray()[index])
              //first approach
              if(no==val) arr.push(timesArray()[index-1],timesArray()[index], timesArray()[index+1])
             //second approach
            return (no===val || timesArray()[index-1]===value||timesArray()[index+1] ===value
        }) as value}
     <option {value}>{value}</option>
        {/each}
     </datalist>
    </span>
```

Comment: First of all, I would consider assigning your datalist element a fixed string value for its id and use that string value as well with your input's list attribute. However, I cannot test if that will resolve your issue.

Comment: What is that `</span>` doing there at the end?

Comment: @ArmenMichaeli . . . I guess it's just too much code copied and pasted. Seems that the script, input and datalist elements are contained within a span element. I am not sure if that would be invalid.

Answer (score 1):

> When the user inputs 13, it should show "12:00", "13:00" and "14:00"

This is simply not going to work. The way data lists are handled is browser-internal behavior. If you just [add the entire list](https://svelte.dev/repl/2230a1ec6a374c9da13a4e55a1e8701c?version=3.50.1) of options and the user types `13`, it will only ever show `13:00` because the browser removes every entry not containing `13`.

To my knowledge there is no way to get the behavior you want using native controls.

> I refuse to use any other select structure as I cant get the arrow keys to work upon select

You simply need a component implementation that is not inaccessible trash. They do exist.

---

As a hack, you could force the typed text to appear in the options, though this has its own drawbacks: The value on selection will different, and if you set an the `value` attribute you can get inconsistent display of those options across browsers (e.g. some may not show the value, some may show value and label).

And you of course get additional unnecessary text in each option.

```html
<script>
    let value = '';
    $: hour = parseInt(value.split(':')[0])
    $: times = isNaN(hour) ? [] :
        Array.from({ length: 24 }).map((_, i) => i)
            .filter(h => Math.abs(h - hour) < 2)
            .map(hour => ({
                value: `${hour.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:00`,
                label: `${hour.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:00 (Match for ${value})`,
            }));
</script>

<input list="list" bind:value />
<datalist id="list">
    {#each times as { value, label }}
        <option {value} {label}/>
    {/each}
</datalist>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f4176c4193b3494dbcf1a196383e78b3?version=3.50.1)

[image: chrome]
[image: firefox]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have now noticed this about datalists. It suprises me I cannot find a single component that doesn't have a good filter function, arrow key functionality and input masking.

Comment: I would not necessarily expect input masking from an auto-complete component, but a good component should be extensible enough to add such a feature afterwards. It is true that most such components are pretty bad (which is why I wrote my  own as some point).